# Destroy_all method usage confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am Learning ruby and am studying a codebase that is using active record in a ruby script.. I dont understand the use of "&" in the .collect statement after the puts command: "removing terminated employees". What kind of data structure is Terminated_ids?

Can the destroy_all method take this datastructure? Dont know what collect command with that weird ampersand does?

I would like to terminate a list of employee ids also using the destory_all. But my data structure is a hash like the following: `[{:emp_id=> "2637"},{:emp_id=> "2637"},{:emp_id=> "2637"},{:emp_id=> "2637"}]`

Please enlighten a ruby noob.. Thank you!

```
class  Maker < ActiveRecord::Base
  host = 'superman.com'
  port = 2000
  sid  = 'ASID'

Maker.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => 'oracle_enhanced',
    :database => "someDB",
    :username => 'user',
    :password => 'passer'
  )
  set_table_name 'WORK.EMPS'
end


puts 'removing terminated employees'
Terminated_ids = Maker.where('term_date IS NOT NULL').collect(&:emp_id) # ???
OtherModel.destroy_all(:emp_id => Terminated_ids)

puts 'removing employees who have been deleted'
OtherModel.find_each do |othermodel|
  if othermodel.email[-12,12] != '@ahsmsweh.com' #do not remove employees with an @ahsmsweh.com email
    pbx_record = Maker.find_by_emp_id(othermodel.emp_id)
    if pbx_record.nil?
      puts "destroying missing record for #{othermodel.email}"
      othermodel.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a short cut for:

```
enumerable.collect(symbol.to_proc)
```

Which behaves the same as:

```
enumerable.collect {|element| element.send(symbol)}
```

Or, in your specific case:

```
Maker.where('term_date IS NOT NULL').collect {|m| m.emp_id}
```

Which yields an array of `emp_id`s (I'm assuming integers).

When `destroy_all` is passed a map containing `:emp_id =>` (an array of integers), it basically searches for all records using a `where` then calls `destroy_all` on the result set:

```
where(:emp_id => [...]).destroy_all
```

For your array of hashes containing `[{:emp_id=> "123"},{:emp_id=> "456"}, ...]`, then you can use the same technique to 'collapse' them:

```
a = [{:emp_id=> "123"},{:emp_id=> "456"}, ...]

OtherModel.destroy_all(:emp_id => a.map(&:values).(&:first))
```

Of course, while readable, I prefer the more straightforward:

```
OtherModel.destroy_all(:emp_id => a.map {|h| h[:emp_id]})
```

Comment: @Imtiaz Ahmad: note that `map` and `collect` in this example by @AlistairIsrael are different names for the same method.